# VBA - How to copy a column once but paste it twice?

Tags: excel, vba

I have a column that I need to copy to the bottom of the same column twice. My code is:

```
Range("AQ2:AQ" & LastRow).Copy Range("AQ" & LastRow + 1)
```

However, I can't just write this line twice because it would quadruple the number of rows, rather than triple them. For example, if column AQ was 4 rows, copying and pasting it once gives 8 rows but then repeating that line will copy and paste the 8, therefore giving 16 rows. However, I only want 12 rows (the 4 rows copied once and pasted twice).

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you will need to do is paste twice. But it is important to note that you will need to update `LastRow` before pasting the second time.

Also something worth mentioning, it is super recommended to use a worksheet object when coding VBA. This will explicitly define your worksheets for your programs and could save you much hassle in the future. Adopt the habit :)

See below code (not tested):

```vb
Sub CopyPaste()

    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet

    Set ws = Sheets("Sheet1")

    'find lastrow
    LastRow = ws.Range("AQ" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'copy
    ws.Range("AQ2:AQ" & LastRow).Copy
    ws.Range("AQ" & (LastRow + 1)).Paste

    'update last row
    LastRow = ws.Range("AQ" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'paste again
    ws.Range("AQ" & (LastRow + 1)).Paste

    'clear clipboard
    Application.CutCopyMode = False

    'clear ws object
    Set ws = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: @isaaacs please don't forget to market this as the answer to close the ticket :)

Comment: This seems overcomplicated.  Wouldn't it be simpler to just do `Range("AQ2:AQ" & LastRow).Copy Range("AQ" & LastRow + 1): Range("AQ2:AQ" & LastRow).Copy Range("AQ" & (LastRow*2))`?

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub copycopy()

Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim i As Integer
Dim lRow As Long
Dim rng As Range

Set sh = Sheets("Sheet1")
'determine range to be copied
Set rng = sh.Range(sh.Range("AQ2"), sh.Range("AQ2").End(xlDown))
'find last row
lRow = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "AQ").End(xlUp).Row + 1
'copy range twice
For i = 1 To 2
    rng.Copy Destination:=sh.Range("AQ" & lRow)
    lRow = sh.Cells(Rows.Count, "AQ").End(xlUp).Row + 1
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: No need for the loop:  the first paste row will be at `LastRow+1` (or `lRow` in your code), and the second will be at `LastRow*2` (or `2*lRow-2` in your code)

Comment: Thanks Chronocidal, I am using this code for multiple pasting, like 30 times the same range one by one in the same column, that is why I do it with loop.